# Autoselect first element of combobox - in component (Child) or in Redux state?

Tags: react-redux, syncfusion

I have cascading comboboxes like in the example https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vbzqr5-nhjatx in my project using react and Redux. When I choose country, the second combobox is updating with data.

What I would need is selecting first item if only one item exists on combobox list. I have no idea if should I change the selected value in Redux state or only in component and then update Redux state. Moreover I would like to have this feature more generic so I thought about overriding method onDataBound, created in ComboboxComponent.

Do you have any idea how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can execute the query using executeQuery method in the change event of the country ComboBox component and assign the results to the State ComboBox component dataSoure instead of assigning the query directly. Based on the executeQuery result, you can assign the preselected value to the ComboBox component using the index property. By referring to the code snippet and documentation sample shared below, you can obtain more information.

```
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import * as React from 'react';
import { ComboBoxComponent } from '@syncfusion/ej2-react-dropdowns';
import { DataManager, Query } from '@syncfusion/ej2-data';

export class Cascading extends SampleBase {
  countryObj;
  stateObj;
  cityObj;
  countryData = [
    { CountryName: 'Australia', CountryId: '2' },
    { CountryName: 'United States', CountryId: '1' },
  ];
  stateData = [
    { StateName: 'Test ', CountryId: '2', StateId: '102' },
    { StateName: 'Tasmania ', CountryId: '2', StateId: '105' },
    { StateName: 'New York', CountryId: '1', StateId: '101' },
  ];
  cityData = [
    { CityName: 'Albany', StateId: '101', CityId: 201 },
    { CityName: 'Beacon ', StateId: '101', CityId: 202 },
    { CityName: 'Emporia', StateId: '102', CityId: 206 },
    { CityName: 'Hampton ', StateId: '102', CityId: 205 },
    { CityName: 'Hobart', StateId: '105', CityId: 213 },
    { CityName: 'Launceston ', StateId: '105', CityId: 214 },
  ];

  countryFields = { value: 'CountryId', text: 'CountryName' };
  stateFields = { value: 'StateId', text: 'StateName' };
  cityFields = { text: 'CityName', value: 'CityId' };
  countryChange() {
    this.stateObj.enabled = this.countryObj.value != null;
    new DataManager(this.stateData)
      .executeQuery(
        new Query().where('CountryId', 'equal', this.countryObj.value)
      )
      .then((e) => {
        this.stateObj.dataSource = e.result;
        this.stateObj.index = e.result.length == 1 ? 0 : null;
        this.stateObj.dataBind();
      });
  }
  stateChange() {
    this.cityObj.enabled = this.stateObj.value != null;
    new DataManager(this.cityData)
      .executeQuery(new Query().where('StateId', 'equal', this.stateObj.value))
      .then((e) => {
        this.cityObj.dataSource = e.result;
        this.cityObj.index = e.result.length == 1 ? 0 : null;
        this.cityObj.dataBind();
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="control-pane">
        <div className="control-section">
          <div id="cascade">
            <div style={{ paddingTop: '35px' }}>
              <ComboBoxComponent
                id="countryList"
                dataSource={this.countryData}
                allowCustom={false}
                ref={(combobox) => {
                  this.countryObj = combobox;
                }}
                popupHeight="auto"
                fields={this.countryFields}
                change={this.countryChange.bind(this)}
                placeholder="Select a country"
              />
            </div>
            <div style={{ paddingTop: '35px' }}>
              <ComboBoxComponent
                id="stateList"
                allowCustom={false}
                ref={(combobox) => {
                  this.stateObj = combobox;
                }}
                popupHeight="auto"
                fields={this.stateFields}
                change={this.stateChange.bind(this)}
                enabled={false}
                placeholder="Select a state"
              />
            </div>
            <div style={{ paddingTop: '35px' }}>
              <ComboBoxComponent
                id="cityList"
                allowCustom={false}
                ref={(combobox) => {
                  this.cityObj = combobox;
                }}
                popupHeight="auto"
                fields={this.cityFields}
                enabled={false}
                placeholder="Select a city"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById('sample'));
root.render(<Cascading />);
```

**Documentation:**

- **executeQuery:
  https://ej2.syncfusion.com/documentation/api/data/dataManager/#executequery**
- **index: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/documentation/api/combo-box#index**

**Sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-esnvgp?file=index.js**

[image]